# TensorFlow Slim Exporting Transfer Learning to tensorflow serving issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) then I used this simple script to validate that my model works which it does:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from nets import inception_v3
from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, imread

slim = tf.contrib.slim


batch_size = 5
image_size = 299

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with slim.arg_scope(inception_v3.inception_v3_arg_scope()):

        imgPath = 'dandelion.jpg'

        #imgPath = '/tmp/rose.jpg'
        testImage_string = tf.gfile.FastGFile(imgPath, 'rb').read()
        testImage = tf.image.decode_jpeg(testImage_string, channels=3)
        processed_image = inception_preprocessing.preprocess_image(testImage, image_size, image_size, is_training=False)
        processed_images = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)



        logits, _ = inception_v3.inception_v3(processed_images, num_classes=5, is_training=False)
        probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp/flowers-models/inception_v3')
        init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
        checkpoint_path, slim.get_model_variables('InceptionV3'))

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init_fn(sess)

            np_image, probabilities = sess.run([processed_images, probabilities])

            probabilities = probabilities[0, 0:]
            sorted_inds = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(-probabilities), key=lambda x: x[1])]

            names = ['daisy', 'dandelion', 'roses', 'sunflowers', 'tulips']
            for i in range(5):
                index = sorted_inds[i]
                print((probabilities[index], names[index]))
```

However my end goal is to load this model inside tensorflow serving and I'm not sure what would be my next step to convert my model into format that serving understand?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow Slim uses the deprecated 'SessionBundle'. I'm currently converting the checkpoints generated by tensorflow/slim (tf.train.saver) to the SavedModel format (tf.saved_model).

'session_bundle.load_session_bundle_from_path' from 'tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/session_bundle.py' returns the session and the meta_graph_def. Intention is to manually build the savedModel (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model), but can't get to the inputs from the meta_graph_def.

Using Tensorflow 1.7 for the moment, downgrading to see if it makes any difference.